# get request on empty lists return 200 status code

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this view:

```
def get(self,request):
    cities = City.objects.filter(State__in=request.GET.getlist('state_id'))
    serializer = citySerializers(cities,many=True)
    return Response({"message": "data loaded!", "data": serializer.data})
```

If I enter a state_id that does not exist on the database it returns me status code 200,I expect it returns 404 for an empty list. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ORM query is converted into:

```
cities = City.objects.filter(State__in=request.GET.getlist('state_id'))
```

into something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM city
WHERE state_id IN (1,4,5)
```

with `1`, `4` and `5` in reality the values stored in the request (`state_id`). But the database does not validate whether `1`, `4`, and `5` are real primary key values, nor does the fact that no cities match is a problem: in that case the result is simply empty.

If we do not care about whether the `state_id`s are valid, but only want to return a 404 in case no `City` can be found, we can use the [**`get_list_or_404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) function:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

def get(self,request):
    cities = get_list_or_404(City, State__in=request.GET.getlist('state_id'))
    serializer = citySerializers(cities, many=True)
    return Response({"message": "data loaded!", "data": serializer.data})
```

But this will still not produce a 404 if certain `state_id`s are invalid ones (as long as at least one is valid, and that one maps on a city, we are fine).

We can also raise a 404 if the `state_id` contains an invalid `State`, for example with:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

def get(self,request):
    state_ids = set(request.GET.getlist('state_id'))
    if len(State.objects.filter(pk=state_ids)) != len(state_ids):
        raise Http404
    cities = get_list_or_404(City, State__in=state_ids)
    serializer = citySerializers(cities, many=True)
    return Response({"message": "data loaded!", "data": serializer.data})
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 404 is returned when you are looking for a specific object which the server could not find. This does not apply to list endpoints where you are trying to get a list either of all objects or based on some criteria(filters). An empty list is very much valid so returning 200 is very much correct